# python script to get and set the values of certain keys in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, scripting

I have a JSON data some thing as shown below:

```
{
  "people": [
    { 
        "name": "John Smith",
        "phone": "615-555-208",
        "emails": ["johnsmith@bogusmail.com","john.smith@workplace.com"],
        "has_licensce": false
    },
    { 
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "phone": "615-555-209",
        "emails": null,
        "has_licensce": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to write a python script to get the values of certain keys and set the values of certain keys of the JSON data.

Example: set people(0).name = Jarvis, should replace John Smith by Jarvis.
Similarly, get people(1).emails should return null.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should parse your JSON data so you can access it from the scripts. You can do it with `json` library from python. Here is an example usage of it:

```
import json

# some JSON:
x =  '{ "people":[{"asd": "AASD"}]}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["people"][0]) 

# and then modify data
y["people"][0] = {"asdasd": "ASDASD"}
y["people"][0]["asdasd"] = "Test"
```

And then you can save it with help of `json.dumps` by converting it into a string and saving that string into the desired file:

```
# convert dictionary into JSON string:
z = json.dumps(y)
print(z)
```

Here is a link for the tutorial:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Comment: The answer is useful, Thanks!. However, I want to write a program which interacts with the user, i.e. if the user enters set people(asd) = ASD,  then this command should change the value of people:asd to ASD from the previous value of  AASD.